# Download multiple plotly plots to PDF Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, plotly

My Shiny App displays a plotly plot for whatever input the user selects. I want a download button that saves ALL the plots inside a PDF file on the user's system. I'm using R markdown for knitting a PDF report and then donwloading it using downloadHandler in Shiny. As of now, I can create each plot individually in my Shiny code and then pass them as a list of parameters to my r markdown file. Since I have a large number of plots (>25) in my actual project, I want to do it in a loop. Here's a reprodcuible example of what I have so far:

```
library(shiny)

dummy.df <- structure(list(
  Tid = structure(
    1:24, .Label = c("20180321-032-000001", 
                     "20180321-032-000003", "20180321-032-000004", "20180321-032-000005", 
                     "20180321-032-000006", "20180321-032-000007", "20180321-032-000008", 
                     "20180321-032-000009", "20180321-032-000010", "20180321-032-000011", 
                     "20180321-032-000012", "20180321-032-000013", "20180321-032-000014", 
                     "20180321-032-000015", "20180321-032-000016", "20180321-032-000017", 
                     "20180321-032-000018", "20180321-032-000020", "20180321-032-000021", 
                     "20180321-032-000022", "20180321-032-000024", "20180321-032-000025", 
                     "20180321-032-000026", "20180321-032-000027"), class = "factor"), 
  Measurand1 = c(4.1938661428, 4.2866076398, 4.2527368322, 
                 4.1653403962, 4.27242291066667, 4.16539040846667, 4.34047710253333, 
                 4.22442363773333, 4.19234076866667, 4.2468291332, 3.9844897884, 
                 4.22141039866667, 4.20227445513333, 4.33310654473333, 4.1927596214, 
                 4.15925140273333, 4.11148968806667, 4.08674611913333, 4.18821475666667, 
                 4.2206477116, 3.48470470453333, 4.2483107466, 4.209376197, 
                 4.04040350253333), 
  Measurand2 = c(240.457556634854, 248.218468503733, 
                 251.064523520989, 255.454918894609, 250.780599536337, 258.342398843477, 
                 252.343710644105, 249.881670507113, 254.937548700795, 257.252509533017, 
                 258.10699153634, 252.191362744656, 246.944795528771, 247.527116069484, 
                 261.060987461132, 257.770850218767, 259.844790397474, 243.046373553637, 
                 247.026385356368, 254.288899315579, 233.51454714355, 250.556819253509, 
                 255.8242909112, 254.938735944406), 
  Measurand3 = c(70.0613216684803, 
                 70.5004961457819, 70.8382322052776, 69.9282599322167, 68.3045749634227, 
                 71.5636835352475, 69.1173532716941, 71.3604764318073, 69.5045949393461, 
                 71.2211656142532, 72.5716638087178, 69.2085312787522, 70.7872214372161, 
                 70.7247180047809, 69.9466984209057, 71.8433220247599, 72.2055956743742, 
                 71.0348320947071, 69.3848050049961, 69.9884660785462, 73.160638501285, 
                 69.7524898841488, 71.1958302879424, 72.6060886025082)), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 24L)
)

# Define UI for application
ui <- fluidPage(
   titlePanel("Download Demo"),
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput(inputId = "variable",
                    label = "Plot Measurand",
                    choices = colnames(dummy.df)[2:11]
        ),
        hr(),
        downloadButton("downloadplot1", label = "Download plots")
      ),
      mainPanel(
         plotlyOutput("myplot1")
      )
   )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {

  # Output graph
  output$myplot1 <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(dummy.df, x = c(1:nrow(dummy.df)), y = ~get(input$variable), type = 'scatter',
            mode = 'markers') %>%
      layout(title = 'Values',
             xaxis = list(title = "Points", showgrid = TRUE, zeroline = FALSE),
             yaxis = list(title = input$variable, showgrid = TRUE, zeroline = FALSE))
  })

  # Creating plots individually and passing them as a list of parameters to RMD
  # Example for the first two measurands
  test.plot1 <- reactive({
    plot_ly(dummy.df, x = c(1:nrow(dummy.df)), y = ~Measurand1, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers')
  })

  test.plot2 <- reactive({
    plot_ly(dummy.df, x = c(1:nrow(dummy.df)), y = ~Measurand2, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers')
  }) 

  output$downloadplot1 <-  downloadHandler(
    filename = "plots.pdf",
    content = function(file){

      tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "report1.Rmd")
      file.copy("download_content.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)

      # Set up parameters to pass to Rmd document
      params <- list(n = test.plot1(), k = test.plot2())

      rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file,
                        params = params,
                        envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
      )
    }
  )
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And my RMD file:

````
---
title: "Report"
output: pdf_document
always_allow_html: yes
params:
  n: NA
  k: NA
---

```{r,echo=FALSE}
library(plotly)
tmpFile <- tempfile(fileext = ".png")
export(params$n, file = tmpFile)
export(params$k, file = tmpFile)
```
````

What I want to do is pass ALL the plots as a parameterized list to rmd, where each of the plot will be plotted in the knitted PDF document and then downloaded.

Something along the lines of:

```
  # IN server
  # Generate plots in a loop
  list.of.measurands <- c("Measurand1", "Measurand2") #....all my measurands

  plots.gen <- lapply(list.of.measurands, function(msrnd){
    plot_ly(dummy.df, x = c(1:nrow(dummy.df)), y = ~msrnd, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers')
  })
```

Pass this list as the parameters to Rmd:

```
# Inside downloadHandler
params <- list(n = plots.gen)
```

And plot all plots in a loop in the rmd file:

````
---
title: "Report"
output: pdf_document
always_allow_html: yes
params:
  n: NA
  k: NA
---

```{r,echo=FALSE}
library(plotly)
tmpFile <- tempfile(fileext = ".png")

for (item in params$n){
  export(item, file = tmpFile)  
}
```
````

This creates a blank report. What am I missing?

**Update**

Following Gregor de Cillia's comment, I changed my plot_ly function to have `y = dummy.df[[msrnd]]`. I have also tried as_widget() but no success in getting plots in my report.

```
plots.gen <- lapply(list.of.measurands, function(msrnd){

as_widget(plot_ly(dummy.df, x = c(1:nrow(dummy.df)), y = dummy.df[[msrnd]], 
                  type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers'))
})
```

Comment: My guess is that the formula interface of `plot_ly` can't handle strings so `y = ~msrnd` does not work in `lapply`.

Comment: That is true. I changed it to `y = dummy.df[[msrnd]]`. Also tried `as_widget()` around my plot_ly() function inside lapply. Still getting a blank report.

Comment: if the problem is with strings, you could try running it through ``eval(parse(text = ...))``?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The Problem**

Okay, so after spending a decent amount of time playing around with `plotly` and knitr, I'm pretty sure that there's a problem with printing `plotly` graphs in a loop while inside a knitr report. I will file an issue at the plotly repository, because there must be some kind of bug. Even when  exporting the graph as .png, then importing it again and displaying it in the `knitr` report, only one graph at a time can be shown. Weird.

**The Solution**

Anyhow, I found a solution without using `knitr` to get a pdf of all graphs that are produced in your Shiny Application. It relies on the `staplr` package to combine PDF files, so you have to install that package and also install the  [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) toolkit.

Afterwards, use the following code I wrote while adapting your Shiny App:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(staplr)

dummy.df <- structure(list(
  Tid = structure(
    1:24, .Label = c("20180321-032-000001", 
                     "20180321-032-000003", "20180321-032-000004", "20180321-032-000005", 
                     "20180321-032-000006", "20180321-032-000007", "20180321-032-000008", 
                     "20180321-032-000009", "20180321-032-000010", "20180321-032-000011", 
                     "20180321-032-000012", "20180321-032-000013", "20180321-032-000014", 
                     "20180321-032-000015", "20180321-032-000016", "20180321-032-000017", 
                     "20180321-032-000018", "20180321-032-000020", "20180321-032-000021", 
                     "20180321-032-000022", "20180321-032-000024", "20180321-032-000025", 
                     "20180321-032-000026", "20180321-032-000027"), class = "factor"), 
  Measurand1 = c(4.1938661428, 4.2866076398, 4.2527368322, 
                 4.1653403962, 4.27242291066667, 4.16539040846667, 4.34047710253333, 
                 4.22442363773333, 4.19234076866667, 4.2468291332, 3.9844897884, 
                 4.22141039866667, 4.20227445513333, 4.33310654473333, 4.1927596214, 
                 4.15925140273333, 4.11148968806667, 4.08674611913333, 4.18821475666667, 
                 4.2206477116, 3.48470470453333, 4.2483107466, 4.209376197, 
                 4.04040350253333), 
  Measurand2 = c(240.457556634854, 248.218468503733, 
                 251.064523520989, 255.454918894609, 250.780599536337, 258.342398843477, 
                 252.343710644105, 249.881670507113, 254.937548700795, 257.252509533017, 
                 258.10699153634, 252.191362744656, 246.944795528771, 247.527116069484, 
                 261.060987461132, 257.770850218767, 259.844790397474, 243.046373553637, 
                 247.026385356368, 254.288899315579, 233.51454714355, 250.556819253509, 
                 255.8242909112, 254.938735944406), 
  Measurand3 = c(70.0613216684803, 
                 70.5004961457819, 70.8382322052776, 69.9282599322167, 68.3045749634227, 
                 71.5636835352475, 69.1173532716941, 71.3604764318073, 69.5045949393461, 
                 71.2211656142532, 72.5716638087178, 69.2085312787522, 70.7872214372161, 
                 70.7247180047809, 69.9466984209057, 71.8433220247599, 72.2055956743742, 
                 71.0348320947071, 69.3848050049961, 69.9884660785462, 73.160638501285, 
                 69.7524898841488, 71.1958302879424, 72.6060886025082)), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 24L)
)

# Define UI for application
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Download Demo"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "variable",
                  label = "Plot Measurand",
                  choices = colnames(dummy.df)[2:11]
      ),
      hr(),
      downloadButton("downloadplot1", label = "Download plots")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput("myplot1")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {

  # Output graph
  output$myplot1 <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(dummy.df, x = c(1:nrow(dummy.df)), y = ~get(input$variable), type = 'scatter',
            mode = 'markers') %>%
      layout(title = 'Values',
             xaxis = list(title = "Points", showgrid = TRUE, zeroline = FALSE),
             yaxis = list(title = input$variable, showgrid = TRUE, zeroline = FALSE))
  })

  # Creating plots individually and passing them as a list of parameters to RMD
  # Example for the first two measurands
  test.plot1 <- reactive({
    plot_ly(dummy.df, x = c(1:nrow(dummy.df)), y = ~Measurand1, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers')
  })

  test.plot2 <- reactive({
    plot_ly(dummy.df, x = c(1:nrow(dummy.df)), y = ~Measurand2, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers')
  }) 

  output$downloadplot1 <-  downloadHandler(
    filename = "plots.pdf",
    content = function(file){

      # Set up parameters to pass to Rmd document
      plots <- list(test.plot1(), test.plot2())

      # Plot indices
      ind_vec <- seq_along(plots)

      # Create tempfiles for all plots
      tfiles <- sapply(ind_vec, FUN = function(x)
        return(tempfile(fileext = ".pdf")))

      # create tempfiles for the plots with the second page deleted
      tfiles_repl <- sapply(ind_vec, FUN = function(x)
        return(tempfile(fileext = ".pdf")))

      # Save the objects as .pdf files
      for (i in ind_vec) {
        # Export files
        export(plots[[i]], tfiles[[i]])

        # Remove second page bc for some reason it is whitespace
        staplr::remove_pages(2, input_filepath = tfiles[[i]], 
                             output_filepath = tfiles_repl[[i]])
      }

      # Combine the plots into one pdf
      staplr::staple_pdf(input_files = tfiles_repl, output_filepath = file)

      # Remove .pdf files
      lapply(tfiles, FUN = file.remove)
      lapply(tfiles_repl, FUN = file.remove)
    }
  )
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I only adapted the code inside the `downloadHandler()` function. This code basically produces `.pdf` files of all plots that are inside the `plots` list (where you later have to specify all your 25 plots, I would do this in a loop). Then, it combines all plots into one `.pdf`, before deleting the second page of each .pdf, which is necessary because for some reason `export()` produces a PDF with the second page being completely blank.

**My Suggestion**

If I were you, I would want to get rid of `plotly` at all, and replace it with `ggplot2` graphs. It would be way easier to do exactly what you want (including the `knitr` solution). Graphs created with `plotly` create an extra layer of complexity, because they are web objects that first have to be converted to static files.

Answer (score 1):

I think @Stanislaus Stadlmann is on point. For some reason, `plotly::export` does not work inside a loop of a rmarkdown file. I suspect it is for the same reason [`knitr::include_graphic` does not work inside a loop](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1260). A workaround is to use the markdown syntax to insert your images. Here is the rmarkdown file that works:

````
---
title: "Report"
output: pdf_document
always_allow_html: yes
params:
  n: NA
---

```{r,echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE, results="asis"}
library(plotly)

for (item in params$n) {
  tmpFile <- tempfile(fileext = ".png")
  export(item, file = tmpFile)
  cat("![](",tmpFile,")\n")
}
```
````

And this is my `downloadplot1` function:

```
  output$downloadplot1 <-  downloadHandler(
    filename = "plots.pdf",
    content = function(file){

      tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "report1.Rmd")
      file.copy("download_content.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)

      list.of.measurands <- c("Measurand1", "Measurand2") #....all my measurands

      plots.gen <- lapply(list.of.measurands, function(msrnd){
        plot_ly(dummy.df, x = c(1:nrow(dummy.df)), y = ~get(msrnd), type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers')
      })

      params <- list(n = plots.gen)

      rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file,
                        params = params,
                        envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
      )
    }
  )
```