# Download multiple files to one PDF shiny

Tags: r, download, shiny

I have an app with multiple pages that each have two plots and two tables.  Is there a way to download all 4 as one file?  A PDF would be nice but if there's a different file type that would work better, I'm open to that.

I tried following the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52066516/download-multiple-plotly-plots-to-pdf-shiny) but I could not get it to work.  I need the plots to be interactive within the app, but they can be static when downloaded.  Any suggestions or is this even possible?  Is there a way to even just print the main panel?

```
library(plotly)
library(shiny)
library(DT)


ui <- fluidPage(

    mainPanel(
         plotlyOutput("SepalPlot"),
         DT::dataTableOutput("Sepal"),
         plotlyOutput("PetalPlot"),
         DT::dataTableOutput("Petal")
    )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

   output$SepalPlot<- renderPlotly({
     plot_ly(iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Sepal.Width, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers')
   })

   sep<-data.frame(c(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width))
   output$Sepal<-renderDataTable({datatable(sep)})

   output$PetalPlot<- renderPlotly({
     plot_ly(iris, x = ~Petal.Length, y = ~Petal.Width, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers')
   })

   pet<-data.frame(c(iris$Petal.Length, iris$Petal.Width))
   output$Petal<-renderDataTable({pet})
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```